# Use Python in Field Calculator to increment up value

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, field-calculator

Please see screenshot for field calculator Python logic.  I have no idea what I'm doing that's any different from [this GISSE answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92565/using-python-in-field-calculator-to-compare-two-fields).

The error I receive is ERROR 000989: Python Syntax Error (invalid syntax line 3).  What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing returning values from a function and assignment. You have to return the modified value, not assign it to the old variable. The correct format for the pre-logic script code would be:

```
def mycalc(ADM2_NAME, Projects):
  if ADM2_NAME == "Bo":
    return (Projects + 1)
  else
    return Projects
```

Although there is an even better (shorter) way of doing this, without using the pre-logic code. Just type in the bottom field:

```
(!Projects! + 1) if (!ADM2_NAME! == "Bo") else !Projects!
```

which increments the value of the `Projects` field value by 1 where the `ADM2_NAME` is `Bo`.

Comment: that was it! both returning the modified value in the function and the single line code work.  much appreciated.